# Why is the constructor not invoked multiple times?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm going through C++ FAQ by Marshall Cline.

Currently playing around with code in point 10.5.

I have this:

```
class Fred
{
public:
  Fred();
  Fred(int x, int y)
  {
    std::cout << "Fred with two ints\n" << std::endl;
  };
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Fred>(3, Fred(4,5));
  return 0;
}
```

I expected to see "Fred with two ints" printed 3 times - but it's only printed once.
Why is that - is it not invoked 3 times?

Comment: Add the copy constructor to see it being used by the vector class.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning me in your example code ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the signature of the `vector` constructor you are invoking:

```
vector( size_type _Count, const Type& _Val, const Allocator& _Alloc = Allocator() );
```

`Fred(4,5)` calls your defined constructor once, and the created instance is passed by reference to the `vector<Fred>` constructor. Then, it [the created instance] is copied 3 times to the vector. The copy operation is performed by using (default) copy constructor; so your constructor is not called more than once.

Comment: That's a very last-century answer :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean? I do apologize if my English is not so good, but I think I described the reason for the behavior.

Comment: In the current standard, there are [*two* constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), one with signature `(size_type)` and one with with signature `(size_type, T const &, Allocator const & = Allocator())` (note: no defaulted value!). This allows for value-initialization of elements, which wasn't previously possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB I modified my answer. It's better now.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling your user-defined constructor once, when you write Fred(4,5).  That gets passed to the vector's constructor, which copies it 3 times into 3 Freds.  This uses your copy constructor, not your default or custom constructor.  If you don't write your own copy constructor, one gets added implicitly, as does an assignment operation.  Below, I've added a copy constructor and assignment operation to show what is being added behind the scenes:

```
class Fred
{
public:
  Fred();  // default constructor
  Fred(int x, int y)  // custom constructor
  {
    std::cout << "Fred with two ints\n" << std::endl;
  };
  Fred(const Fred&); // copy constructor
  Fred& operator=(const Fred&);  // assignment operator overload
};
```

The copy constructor:
Fred(const Fred&);
Is what is being called when the vector constructor copies your Fred into the 3 contained Freds.  If you implement it yourself, you'll see it called 3 times.  Here's a full demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Fred
{
private:
    int x,y;

public:
    Fred()  // default constructor
    {
        cout << "Fred's default constructor\n";
    }
    Fred(int x, int y)  // custom constructor
    {
        cout << "Fred's custom constructor\n" << std::endl;
    };
    Fred(const Fred& rhs)   // copy constructor -- NOTE rhs stands for "right-hand-side"
        :x(rhs.x),y(rhs.y)
    {
        cout << "Fred's copy constructor\n";
    }
    Fred& operator=(const Fred& rhs)  // assignment operator overload
    {
        if(&rhs != this)
        { 
            cout << "Fred's assignment overload\n";
            x = rhs.x;
            y = rhs.y;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Fred fred;  // calls default constructor
    vector<Fred> myFreds(3,Fred(4,5));  // calls custom constructor, then copy constructor 3 times.
    fred = myFreds[0]; // calls assignment overload

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

Fred's default constructor
Fred's custom constructor
Fred's copy constructor
Fred's copy constructor
Fred's copy constructor
Fred's assignment overload

If you disable the copy constructor and assignment overload, you'll get an error where you try to use them.  If you use C++11, if you can disable them by declaring them as above, followed by = delete;

```
Fred(const Fred&) = delete;
```

If you don't use C++11, you can effectively disable them by declaring them in private:

```
private:
Fred(const Fred&);  // NOTE: Don't define this function.
```

Once it's disabled, you'll see that your program no longer compiles because it's trying to access functions that are disabled.  It only compiled for you because you allowed these to be added implicitly by not defining them yourself.